# Php Next page and Previous page fetch data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

am using search items to filter the city,gender,profession and state.
it should display 3 rows per page.
but it display the first page. when i presss the last page, again it comes back to home page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{                           
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("nursingcarein",$con);

    if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } else { 
        $page=1; 
    };

    $start_from = ($page-1) * 3;
    /*pass the values(city,gender,profession,state) frm search */

    $city=$_POST['city'];

    $gender=$_POST['gender'];

    $profession=$_POST['profession'];

    $state=$_POST['state'];
```

Comment: I think the part we need to see is missing from the code. Like the actual SQL query.

Comment: where is your link code...

Comment: pagination link 1,2,3..code?

Comment: you often use LIMIT for this LIMIT 0,30 (page 1 30 items per page)

Comment: this is my code link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-8W8xhQSYwbVhZjM55kQtoP0RWnU5gAjsWi8oDbOO8o/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but the following code :

```
LIMIT $start_from, 3
```

Does not work if `$start_from` is greater than 3.
If you want 3 records, you have to do this :

```
$end = $start_from + 3;
// Your code here
LIMIT $start_from, $end
```